# How do you assign a transaction with EF4 CodeFirst CTP5 without using TransactionScopes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-4, code-first

I am attempting to perform functional tests against a live database, to make sure my linq queries are translating into SQL correctly.  I want to do this by using transactions, so that one functional test does not affect another.

The problem is, I cannot find any way in the API to utilize transactions correctly.  I can retrieve a new `DbTransaction` via `MyDbContext.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction()`, however, I cannot find anyway to actually use this transaction.

All documentation I can find about the `BeginTransaction()` call, is you assign the transaction object to the `SqlCommand` via a `cmd.Transaction` call for the command you are performing actions with.  However, with EF4 CTP5, there is no way to access the `SqlCommand` used for the queries.

Thus, I can't figure out how to use the transaction I have begun with `BeginTransaction()`.

I do not want to use `TransactionScope` objects, mostly because Sql CE 4 does not support them, and I would prefer to use a local database and not go across a network.  Sql CE 4 DOES support transactions retrieved via `BeginTransaction()`, I just can't figure out how with code first.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

---

**Edit**: After some emails with Microsoft, it seems that `TransactionScope()` calls are meant to be the primary way to use transactions with EF4.  To get `TransactionScope` to work with Sql CE you have to explicitely open the database connection prior to starting the transaction, for example

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void My_SqlCeScenario ()
    {
        using (var context = new MySQLCeModelContext()) //ß derived from DbContext
        {
            ObjectContext objctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
            objctx.Connection.Open(); //ß Open your connection explicitly
            using (TransactionScope tx = new TransactionScope())
            {

                var product = new Product() { Name = "Vegemite" };
                context.Products.Add(product);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            objctx.Connection.Close(); //ß close it when done!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this article on MSDN might help [Managing Connections & Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx) then scroll down to the heading **Transactions and Entity Framework**. That's where I would start.

**EDIT:** Here's a better one: [How To: Manage Transactions in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx)

Comment: The second article uses TransactionScopes, which I can't use.  The first article was good but doesn't seem to help.  It looks like CTP5 is bugged and `EnlistTransaction()` doesn't work correctly, as `Context.SaveChanges()` still triggers the creation of a new transaction, thus causing an exception due to nested transactions

Comment: I apologize, I seemed to overlook the part about using SQL CE and it not supporting TransactionScopes, let me see if I can come up with something better

Comment: No worries, I still gave you rep :).  The more I read those links, the more it seems like EF4 has bugs and design issues in regards to transactions as a whole.  I ended up sending Scott Guthrie an email, and I'll post here if I get a response.

Comment: Well, after several emails it seems like `TransactionScope`s are the way to go for EF4 transactions, but Sql CE has known bugs that prevent them from being used.  I guess I'll switch to using `TransactionScope` and Sql Express for now, until Sql CE is more stable.

Answer (score 1):

This is cheesy, but may be your only option here:

```
((EntityConnection)myObjectContext.Connection).StoreConnection.BeginTransaction(...
```